# i just want to print several images that fetched from a method named repaint and to all these images seperatly on custom cells of table in ios

Tags: json, uitableview, ios7, custom-cell

```
// custom delegate that takes value in retrieved data array ::
-(void)repaint:(NSMutableArray *)retrievedData
{
    if (retrievedData.count > 0)
    {
        userObj = [retrievedData objectAtIndex:0];

        url_Img1=@"http://kiascenehai.pk/assets/uploads/event-images/50x50-thumb/";
        url_Img2=userObj.event_dpURL;
        url_Img_FULL = [url_Img1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:url_Img2];

       [tableData addObjectsFromArray:retrievedData];
        [table reloadData];
      }
}
```

This code is printing a single image several times.

```
[[cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL       URLWithString:url_Img_FULL]]]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably this line, where you always take the first object from the array:

```
userObj = [retrievedData objectAtIndex:0];
//                                     ^
```

Use *Fast Enumeration* instead:

```
-(void)repaint:(NSMutableArray *)retrievedData
{
    for (WhateverType *userObj in retrievedData)
    {
        url_Img1=@"http://kiascenehai.pk/assets/uploads/event-images/50x50-thumb/";
        url_Img2=userObj.event_dpURL;
        url_Img_FULL = [url_Img1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:url_Img2];

       [tableData addObjectsFromArray:retrievedData];
        [table reloadData];
      }
}
```

Note: none of the variables in that method should be an instance variable, other than `tableData` and `table`.  Also that URL manipulation code looks dodgy, but that's a different story...

Comment: sorry, but i am not able to understand this and also its not working using fast enumeration as: for (userobj in retreivedData), it still displaying the same image several times